# How to define a Cloudformation ECR RepositoryPolicyText that can be referenced by other ECR repository definitions?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecr

I was trying to create a RepositoryPolicyText which can be referenced by other ecr repositories defined in the cloudformation template. Something like this:

```
MyRepository: 
  Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
  Properties: 
    RepositoryName: "test-repository"
    RepositoryPolicyText: !Ref MyRepositoryPolicy
```

I tried to put in a managed policy, but it don't allow to create principal in there.

Is there any other way I can get the RepositoryPolicyText to work by reference?

Instead of replicating the RepositoryPolicyText, I can write once and reference in other repository definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [CloudFormation parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) with a default string, then this parameter can be shared across resources.

```
Parameters:
  repoPolicy:
    Type: String
    Default: '{"Statement":[ {"Sid" : "a", "Effect" : "Allow", "Principal" : "*", "Action" : "ecr:*" } ]}'
Resources:
  repoA:
    Type: 'AWS::ECR::Repository'
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: cfnrepoa
      RepositoryPolicyText: !Ref repoPolicy
  repoB:
    Type: 'AWS::ECR::Repository'
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: cfnrepob
      RepositoryPolicyText: !Ref repoPolicy
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see how it would work as there are no ECR types in the parameter section. Maybe string? How do you think it would work? Do you have any examples to give? Thanks!

Comment: @Kenji Added an example to the answer

Comment: Now I see! Thank you! BTW, I did a workaround keeping the policy text the same, but creating the cloudformation using Ansible and loops, so, now I can loop through the names of ECR repositories and create them using the same CF template.